# Redirect to subfolder's subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am needing to redirect a subfolder to a subfolder of that same subfolder. I was hoping to do the following:

`Redirect http://domain.com/subfolder/ http://domain.com/subfolder/subfolder`

...but that creates a loop. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Also trying something like this, with no luck (it doesn't do anything):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com\/subdomain$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/subdomain/subdomain$ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and put this code in your .htaccess (under DOCMENT_ROOT)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(subfolder)/((?!subfolder).*)$ $1/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```